# Problem with Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been working on this problem based on Inequalities for more than 40 minutes now, but it seems that I can't figure it out... the problem is the following:

"At a party there are n people. Every person shakes the hand just one time with each other. How many people have to be at the party as the number of hand shakes must be more than 50?"

the result is: $n\ge 11$

I don't understand how to create the inequality...

I assigned $n$=number of people, $x$=hand shakes and I don't understand how to continue. I tried doing $x=\frac n{n-1}$ and then $\frac n{n-1}\ge 50$ but It doesn't work obviously.

Comment: For a group of $n$ people, how many handshakes will occur?

Comment: I don't know, that's what I'm trying to understand. Maybe n(n-1)?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is $n(n-1)$?

Comment: Because everyone(n) has to shake the hand with each other just one time so with (n-1). That's what I thought. But it's obviously wrong.

Comment: For a handshake, you need a pair. How many pairs of people can you form?

Comment: I think the number of people (n)/2 to form the pairs.

Comment: $\frac n2$? But what if you had, say, 3 people?

Comment: Uhm... I think we can't form pairs if they are odd. Am I wrong?

Comment: Suppose you have persons $A,B$ and $C$. Then $(A,B),(A,C),(B,C)$

Comment: Yes so, for example, "A" shakes the hand just one time.

Comment: Ok, consider this - you have 2 numbered slots and $n$ objects to choose from, to place there. For slot 1, you have $n$ options, and so for slot 2, you have $(n-1)$ options. Now, suppose the slots were not distinguishable. Then placing object $A$ in slot 1 and $B$ in slot 2 is the same as placing $B$ in slot 1 and $A$ in slot 2

Comment: Well, $A$ shake hands with both $B$ and $C$

Comment: yes, sorry, I mean just one time per person.

Comment: Hmm, well yes, a person will shake hands (usually?) one at a time. What we want to do is how many hands he shakes in total; rather the total number of handshakes

Comment: yes, so what about the objects? they can be both put in the slots as you prefer. right?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the case for handshakes

Comment: yes, it would be wrong

Comment: So I have to divide by two then. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

There are $n(n-1)/2$ (unique) handshakes in total. The division by $2$ is the because say, person $A$ shakes hand with person $B$, only one (not two) handshake is counted.

Then, we want:
$$
50\leq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\iff 100\leq n^2-n.
$$
Note that if $n\leq 10$, then $(n-10)(n+9)\leq 0\implies n^2-n\leq 90<100$. So $n\geq 11$ is necessary. And you can check that $n\geq 11$ is enough:
$$
n\geq 11\implies(n-11)(n+10)\geq 0\implies n^2-n\geq 110\ge 100.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the Help!!!